# how do I solve build time error after project initialize in Xcode?

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-authentication

This is the error I got:
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BarberApp-beyxycoeyxvbafccvpatsjhfeicq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-logger.build/Objects-normal/arm64/react_native_log.o /Users/orelbarclay/Documents/Projects/barber-app/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/logger/react_native_log.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-logger' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

Comment: Try to use use_flipper!() in Podfile.

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting a few more similar errors like: The following build commands failed:
 CompileC /Users/orelbarclay/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BarberApp-beyxycoeyxvbafccvpatsjhfeicq/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCT-Folly.build/Objects-normal/arm64/dynamic.o /Documents/Projects/barber-app/ios/Pods/RCT-Folly/folly/dynamic.cpp normal arm64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RCT-Folly' from project 'Pods').

Is there a special syntax?
(1 failure)